# pandas using plot to draw a line graph, the time is not continuous, how to make the line continuous？

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this：

```
import pandas as pd

dataA = [["2005-1-20", "9:35", 5], ["2005-1-20", "9:40", 8], ["2005-1-20", "9:45", 7],
["2005-1-20","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-20", "10:25", 2], ["2005-1-20", "10:30", 2],
["2005-1-20", "10:35", 15], ["2005-1-20", "10:40", 6], ["2005-1-20", "10:45", 1], 
["2005-1-20", "10:50", 11], ["2005-1-20", "10:55", 12], ["2005-1-20", "11:00", 7], 
["2005-1-21", "9:35", 2], ["2005-1-21", "9:40", 3], ["2005-1-21", "9:45", 4],
["2005-1-21","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-21", "10:25", 5], ["2005-1-21", "10:30", 9],
["2005-1-21", "10:35", 4], ["2005-1-21", "10:40", 3], ["2005-1-21", "10:45", 5], 
["2005-1-21", "10:50", 4], ["2005-1-21", "10:55", 4], ["2005-1-21", "11:00", 8],
["2005-1-22", "9:35", 12], ["2005-1-22", "9:40", 13], ["2005-1-22", "9:45", 14],
["2005-1-22","9:50", 14], ["2005-1-22", "10:25", 15], ["2005-1-22", "10:30",19],
["2005-1-22", "10:35", 14], ["2005-1-22", "10:40", 13], ["2005-1-22", "10:45", 15], 
["2005-1-22", "10:50", 14], ["2005-1-22", "10:55", 14], ["2005-1-22", "11:00", 18]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["date", "min", "val"])

df['min']=pd.to_datetime(df['min'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time
```

When I use plot to draw a time series line chart, because there is no data from 9:50-10:20, the line is not continuous：

```
df = df.pivot('min','date','val')
df.plot()
```

Image like this：
[image: pic]

How to ignore the 9:50-10:20 time period and draw a continuous line？

Comment: To make it clear, do you want there to be a break in the chart between 9:50 and 10:20 where you don't have any data?

Comment: I don't want there to be a break in the chart

Comment: OK, so on the chart that you posted you already have the line between 9:50 and 10:20. What exactly do you want to change there?

Comment: I want to connect the 9:50 point directly to the 10:20 point, and the distance between the two points is only 5 minutes, instead of automatically filling in the 30-minute interval as it is currently

Comment: Got it, please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to connect the 9:50 point directly to the 10:20 point, and the distance between the two points is only 5 minutes, instead of automatically filling in the 30-minute interval as it is currently

If you convert `min` column to strings, it will display it as a categorical variable, with equal distances between the points:

```
df['min'] = pd.to_datetime(df['min'], format='%H:%M').dt.time.astype(str)

df = df.pivot('min','date','val')
df.plot()
```

Output:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue myself and found that you need to create a datetime index with all of your desired minutes.

```
from datetime import timedelta

# get the full datetime as a column in a dataframe
dts = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str)+' '+df['min'].astype(str)), columns=['timestamp'])

# get the minimum datetime and maximum datetime
min_date = dts['timestamp'].min()
max_date = dts['timestamp'].max()

# work out how many minutes this is
minutes = int((max_date-min_date).total_seconds()/60)

# create timestamps for each of the minutes
timestamps = pd.DataFrame(pd.DatetimeIndex([(min_date + timedelta(minutes=x, seconds=0, milliseconds=0)).replace(second=0, microsecond=0) for x in range(0,minutes)], freq='min'), columns=['timestamp'])

# set the index
timestamps = timestamps.set_index('timestamp')

# add the original datetimes into your dataframe for joining purposes
df2 = pd.concat([df, dts], axis=1)

df2

date    min val timestamp
0   2005-01-20  09:35:00    5   2005-01-20 09:35:00
1   2005-01-20  09:40:00    8   2005-01-20 09:40:00
2   2005-01-20  09:45:00    7   2005-01-20 09:45:00
3   2005-01-20  09:50:00    4   2005-01-20 09:50:00

#explode your values into individual columns, by timestamp    
vals = pd.concat([df2['timestamp'], pd.get_dummies(df2['val'])], axis=1).set_index('timestamp')

# join the big timestamps series to the exploded vals (left join)
timestamps = timestamps.join(vals)

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   11  12  13  14  15  18  19
timestamp                                                               
2005-01-20 09:35:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2005-01-20 09:36:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

# get rid of any nans
timestamps = timestamps.fillna(0).astype(int)

# sum across the columns
timestamps = pd.DataFrame(timestamps.sum(axis=1), columns=['value'])


timestamp
2005-01-20 09:35:00    1
2005-01-20 09:36:00    0
2005-01-20 09:37:00    0
2005-01-20 09:38:00    0

# get the date ranges into their own series
timestamps['date'] = timestamps.index.floor('d')
final = pd.get_dummies(timestamps['date']).multiply(timestamps['value'], axis="index")

# group by times
final.groupby([final.index.time]).sum()

2005-01-20  2005-01-21  2005-01-22
00:00:00    0   0   0
00:01:00    0   0   0
00:02:00    0   0   0
00:03:00    0   0   0
00:04:00    0   0   0
... ... ... ...
23:55:00    0   0   0
23:56:00    0   0   0
23:57:00    0   0   0
23:58:00    0   0   0
23:59:00    0   0   0
1440 rows × 3 columns


final.groupby([final.index.time]).sum().plot.line(figsize=(20,10))
```

[image]

Comment: When executing your code in jupyter, error occurs:' Index' object has no attribute 'floor'，timestamps['value'] also occurs error

Comment: There was an error in the line where it summed up across columns - it wasn't setting it to a dataframe with column `value`. I've changed it. Not sure why you get index not having floor though. This line works for me in pandas 1.1.5 and python 3.8.

Comment: This time it is correct, but the result graph is very strange. It is not 3 lines, but several bar bars. You could try it